# Users cannot use crontab after password security upgrade

Tags: linux, cron, password, pam

I have a box being upgraded from CentOS 5 to CentOS 6. On the original server, all users have MD5 passwords. The upgraded server is now using SHA-512 passwords.

Users who have changed their password and have a SHA-512 password in `/etc/shadow` since the upgrade are able to use `crontab` successfully, but users who have not changed their password and still have an old MD5 password cannot use `crontab`. The error message they receive is:

```
Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info
You (_username_) are not allowed to access to (crontab) because of pam configuration.
```

I've looked at `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` ([you can too](http://pastebin.com/Hm4AYvGF)) but I'm not exactly sure what to tweak to permit access to crontab for users who have not yet changed their passwords.

I'm well aware that I can force everyone to change their passwords with `chage -d 0`, and users who change their password will regain access to crontab (and whatever else might be broken) but I have a few users where I need to edit their crontab before their next login, and using `crontab -e -u _username_` as root also fails with exactly the same error as above.

Strangely, this issue didn't show up on my dev box; I've run into this on the staging box just prior to deployment. Users on the dev box with old MD5 passwords can access crontab just fine, and the `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` is identical. The dev and staging boxes are supposed to be identical, aside from their IP addresses. I suspect I've missed something really obvious and stupid...

So my question is, how can I enable access to crontab for users who haven't yet changed their passwords and been SHA-512 hashed? Or, how can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to fix this moments after posting the question.

It turns out that the `/etc/shadow` entries for the affected MD5 password users had somehow had the field after the hashed password duplicated, causing PAM to be unable to interpret the line. In other words, a bad cut and paste job.

I haven't had enough coffee...

Comment: There's a tool called `vipw` that should prevent this kind of mistake.  `vipw -s` edits the shadow file.

Comment: Unfortunately `vipw` (which I was using) doesn't prevent my wireless mouse from going nuts due to interference, low battery, or whatever was causing it to misbehave...

Comment: Thanks for this. Simple solution to something I was way overthinking.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too and it turned out that /etc/shadow did not have an entry for that user. Using pwck added the user and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issues. If you do not need some exact password for account, just run:

```
pwconv
```