# edit crontab for apache

Tags: apache-2.2, cron, pam

I am transfering crontabs from an old server (centos 5.5) to a a new (centos 6.0) and there is a problem with (the most important) user apache. On the new server I am getting the following:

```
root@newserver $ crontab -u apache -e

Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info
You (apache) are not allowed to access to (crontab) because of pam configuration.
```

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Does http://serverfault.com/questions/408331/users-cannot-use-crontab-after-password-security-upgrade help ?

Comment: a bit, i guess the problem is there is no record for apache in /etc/shadow but i am not sure if adding it is correct.

Comment: All /etc/passwd entries must have a corresponding /etc/shadow entry -- its not just nice its the law.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is being caused because you have no entry for apache in your /etc/shadow file. It should contain a entry like this

```
apache:!!:15168::::::
```

I just tested this on a C6.3 system and removing it gives exactly the same error you are seeing.